# Paratrooper falling in a 4km^2 squared field with trees, probability of him not getting stuck

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometric-probability

paratrooper is falling in a square field with a side of 2km.
in each corner of the field there is a big tree.
the paratrooper gets stuck in the tree if he falls within a 1/11 km distance of the tree.
What is the probability of him NOT getting stuck?

I solved it like this.
each corner tree takes up a space of
${\pi r^2 \over 4}$ because its in the corner.  ${r = \frac {1} {11}}$

The field has 4 such trees, resulting in an area of  4${\pi r^2 \over 4}$ or 0.025
probability of him getting stuck is 0.006,
or not getting stuck      $${1-0.006 = 0.993 }$$

However another person has solved this, and got an answer of ${1\over2}$

I am not sure if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: You are correct.  I can't imagine what the other person is doing, except maybe saying, "There are two possibilities: he gets stuck or he doesn't, so ..."

Comment: Then the air resistance kicks in...

Answer (score 1):

**Graphical comment** and simulation:

It suffices to look only at the "southwest" $1$km square with one tree at the "origin."

Simulate (in R) $n = 10\,000$ parachute drops.
First, plot all landings in cyan. Then over-plot
in in red the drops that end in getting stuck.

```
set.seed(2021); n = 10^5
X = runif(n); Y = runif(n)
plot(X, Y, pch=".", col="cyan4")

# gets stuck (small x and y)
x = X[X^2+Y^2 <= (1/11)^2]
y = Y[X^2+Y^2 <= (1/11)^2]
points(x, y, pch=".", col="red")
```

[image]

Find the proportion of the points in which the paratrooper does
not get get stuck.

```
mean(X^2+Y^2 > (1/11)^2)
[1] 0.99365       # aprx 0.9935091
2*sd(X^2+Y^2 > (1/11)^2)/sqrt(n)
[1] 0.0005023839  # 95% margin of sim error
```

So the simulated probability is $0.9936 \pm 0.0005.$

The **exact probability** (to four places) is $0.9935$ as you have said and @saulspatz has agreed.

```
1 - pi*.25*(1/11)^2
[1] 0.9935091
```